# How to create a Vertical Navigation Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here is a menu using HTML and CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/DqvxR/190/)
Menu items are placed horizontally and submenus use vertical layout. How should main menu items be changed to be layed out vertically too?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>item1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>subitem1</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem1</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh sorry Check this page please http://jsfiddle.net/DqvxR/190/

Comment: this is not a good fit for Q&A format. anyways visit this link and copy http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/menudesigns/category/C19/ the menu you want

Comment: You can download pre developed menus from google and study them to make your own. Or use them. One such is: http://cssmenumaker.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some minor changes and it will work as vertical. and as you looking some more style to add on it you can do it easily.

> Check this fiddle [**CLICK HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/QuKXz/)

```
#menu
{
    width: 120px;/*change width*/
}
#menu li
{

    display: block; /*keep it block*/
    }
#menu ul
{

    top: 0; /*change this */
    left: 100%; /*change this */
}
#menu ul li:first-child > a:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:-13px; /* change this*/
    top:7px; /* change this*/
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent; /* change this*/
    /*border-right: 5px solid transparent;*/ /*don't need this*/
    border-right: 8px solid #444; /* change this*/
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
    border-right-color: #04acec;  /* change this*/
}
```

I wrote in comments what to change specific to achieve what you want. You can manipulate more